# atom IDE install on ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, atom

I try to install ATOM IDE on ubuntu but I have an error.how I can be fixed this error.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

throw this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 atom : Depends: gconf2
        Depends: gconf-service
        Depends: python but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and the run in command line

```
  sudo apt --fix-broken install

    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Ign:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 gconf2-common all 3.2.6-4ubuntu1
    Err:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 libgconf-2-4 amd64 3.2.6-4ubuntu1
      404  Not Found
    Err:3 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 gconf-service-backend amd64 3.2.6-4ubuntu1
      404  Not Found
    Err:4 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 gconf-service amd64 3.2.6-4ubuntu1
      404  Not Found
    Err:5 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 gconf2 amd64 3.2.6-4ubuntu1
      404  Not Found
    Err:6 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.14-2ubuntu2
      404  Not Found
    Err:7 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 python-minimal amd64 2.7.14-2ubuntu1
      404  Not Found
    Err:8 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.14-2ubuntu2
      404  Not Found
    Err:9 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 libpython-stdlib amd64 2.7.14-2ubuntu1
      404  Not Found
    Err:10 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 python amd64 2.7.14-2ubuntu1
      404  Not Found
    Err:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe i386 gconf2-common all 3.2.6-4ubuntu1
      404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gconf/gconf2-common_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_all.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gconf/libgconf-2-4_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gconf/gconf-service-backend_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gconf/gconf-service_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gconf/gconf2_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.14-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python-minimal_2.7.14-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.14-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/libpython-stdlib_2.7.14-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python_2.7.14-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ seams to a return a 404, have you tried running apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your repository server from `ir.archive.ubuntu.com` to `archive.ubuntu.com` (for example) in /etc/apt/sources.list file and then do update, upgrade and fix broken dependencies.